How to obtain the pucker angles of a molecular ring?
The structure of the system is a ciclohexane whose conformational preference is describe in the following image:

The name of this conformational preference is "chair". Because it resembles a chair.
In the Cremer-Pople coordinates 1, this conformational preference is classified as 1C4.
In my case, the coordinates of my system are:
 N6    -2.342     0.000    -0.682
 C1    -3.132    -1.218    -0.622
 C2    -3.991    -1.206     0.644
 N3    -4.799    -0.000     0.783
 C4    -3.991     1.205     0.645
 C5    -3.132     1.219    -0.621

Its conformational preference is 1C4. Nevertheless, I want to obtain the Cremer-Pople coordinates for a set of molecules (~400). For this reason I wrote a python code:
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
import numpy
import math
from numpy.linalg import norm

#
# Load the file with the ring coordinates
#
inputfile=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
#
# Assign the coordinates to atom matrix
#
j=0
atoms=numpy.zeros((6,3),dtype='float64')
for line in inputfile:
    sline=line.split()
    header=sline[0]
    for i in range(0,3,1):
        atoms[j][i]=float(sline[i+1])
    j=j+1
#
# Determine the puckering coordinates   
#
pucker_coord=numpy.zeros((3,3),dtype='float64')
#for i in range(0,3,1):
#   for j in range(0,3,1):
#       if 2*(i+1) > 5:
#           pucker_coord[i][j]=atoms[0][j]-atoms[i][j]
#       else:   
#           pucker_coord[i][j]=atoms[2*(i+1)][j]-atoms[2*i][j]


for j in range(0,3,1):
    pucker_coord[2][j]=atoms[1][j]-atoms[5][j]
    pucker_coord[1][j]=atoms[3][j]-atoms[1][j]
    pucker_coord[0][j]=atoms[5][j]-atoms[3][j]

#
# Normal vector to the plane make up of puckering coordinates           
#
n=numpy.zeros((1,3),dtype='float64')
n=numpy.cross(pucker_coord[1,:],pucker_coord[0,:])
#
# Distances Matrix
#
distances=numpy.zeros((5,3),dtype='float64')
for i in range(4,-1,-1):
    for j in range(0,3,1):
        distances[i][j]=atoms[i+1][j]-atoms[i][j]
#
#  atom's orientation vector relative to the plane, pi. 
#
p=numpy.zeros((4,3),dtype='float64')
for i in range(3,-1,-1):
    p[i,:]=numpy.cross(distances[i,:],distances[i+1,:])
#
# creation of a vector qi orthogonal to p2i+1 and ai:           
#
q=numpy.zeros((3,3),dtype='float64')
for i in range(2,-1,-1):
    if 2*i+1 > 4:
        k=1
        q[i,:]=numpy.cross(pucker_coord[i,:],p[k,:])
    else:
        q[i,:]=numpy.cross(pucker_coord[i,:],p[2*i+1,:])
#
# Tetha angles, puckering angles        
#
tetha=numpy.zeros((1,3),dtype='float64')
for i in range(0,3,1):
    tetha[0,i]=90-numpy.rad2deg(math.acos((numpy.dot(q[i,:],n))/(numpy.dot(norm(q[i,:],1),norm(n,1)))))
#
# Debugging
#
print(atoms)
print(pucker_coord)
print(n)
print(distances)
print(p)
print(q)
print(tetha)

To write this code, I followed the instructions to write it 2:

When I execute this python code, for the puckering angles, I obtain: 8.21794088 8.2322812  8.07777518. But it should be 35.26    35.26   35.26.
What am I doing wrong?
How can I solve this issue?
PS: If this is resolved, the reward can be nicer than just the bounty.
References
1   General definition of ring puckering coordinates
D. Cremer and J. A. Pople
Journal of the American Chemical Society 1975 97 (6), 1354-1358
DOI: 10.1021/ja00839a011
2   Puckering Coordinates of Monocyclic Rings by Triangular Decomposition
Anthony D. Hill and Peter J. Reilly
Journal of Chemical Information and Modeling 2007 47 (3), 1031-1035
DOI: 10.1021/ci600492e

First of all, the answer you've stated as correct is actually not. A puckering angle of $35.26° = \sin^{-1} (1/\sqrt{3})$ is for ideal $1\text{C}_4$ conformation, which has torsion (endocyclic dihedral) angles $60°$, $-60°$, $60°$, $-60°$, $60°$, $-60°$. Your system has torsion angles $53.08°$, $-51.72°$, $51.75°$, $-53.08°$, $56.02°$, $-56.04°$, so the puckering angles should also deviate from ideal value.
Your code also does not correspond to the instruction from Hill et al. In particular,

You use wrong indices to define pucker_coord. The commented part of the code is pretty close, but it should be
atoms[0][j]-atoms[2*i][j] instead of atoms[0][j]-atoms[i][j].
You should have $6$ distances and $5$ p, not $5$ distances and $4$ p, because there is also $\mathbf{r}_5 = \mathbf{x}_0 - \mathbf{x}_5$ and $\mathbf{p}_5 = \mathbf{r}_4 \times \mathbf{r}_5$. It also means that you don't need to check if 2*i+1 > 4 when you calculate q.
Your p is numerated from $0$, while in the instruction it is from $1$. Quick way to fix that is to use p[2*i,:] instead of p[2*i+1,:] when you calculate q.
When you are using norm(..., 1) it means that you are calculating $L_1$ norm of the vector (the sum of the absolute values) while you need $L_2$. So the correct expression should use norm(..., 2) or just the default norm(...).

The correct version of the code, which also removes the unnecessary iterations over numpy array and uses some other simplifications is provided below:
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

# we use roll to obtain the shifted version of array
# for example, [1, 3, 7] transforms to [3, 7, 1]
distances = np.roll(atoms, -1, 0) - atoms

# here we use a trick that if r0 = x1 - x0 and r1 = x2 - x1
# we have r0 + r1 = x2 - x0, which is a0, etc
a = distances[::2] + distances[1::2]
n = np.cross(a[1,:], a[0,:])

# we only calculate p1, p3, p5, other values are not needed
p = np.cross(distances[::2], distances[1::2])

# it evaluates all cross products of each row of a 
# and the corresponding row of p
q = np.cross(a, p)

# we use axis=1 to calculate norm of different rows of q
v = np.dot(q, n)/norm(q, axis=1)/norm(n)

# since arcsin x + arccos x = 90 degrees, we can just use arcsin
theta = np.rad2deg(np.arcsin(v))
print(*theta)
which gives
-31.368156958497842 -29.087558290581242 -31.33837716365657
for your system.
